# How to use a while() loop within a for() loop in R

Tags: r, for-loop, while-loop

I'm new to R, so most of my code is most likely wrong. However, I was wondering how to use a while() loop within a for() loop. I'm trying to simulate rolling a pair of dice several times if the total 2,3,7,11,or 12 then I stop. If the total 4,5,6,8,9, or 10 then I continue to the roll the dice until the initial total appears or 7. I'm trying to find the average number of rolls it take to end the game

```
count = 0
x = NULL
for (i in 1:10) {
  x[i] = c(sample(1:6,1) +sample(1:6,1))
  if(x[i] == c(2||3||7||11||12)) {
    if(TRUE) {count = count +1}
  } else { while(x[i] == c(4||5||6||8||9||10)) {
    x[i +1] = c(sample(1:6,1)+sample(1:6,1))
    if(x[i+1] == c(x[i]||7)) {
      if(TRUE){count = count + x[i+1]}
    }
  }
  }
}
print(count)
```

Comment: your main problem is that you should use `x[i] %in% c(2,3,7,11,12)` instead of the `||` operator (*or* `x[i]==2 || x[i]==3 || ...`)

Comment: What surprises me are the numbers chosen by you. Wouldn't the game be simpler if the first group of numbers were 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, the other group 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, and the "escape" from the second group would be the initial number OR 1? The probabilities stay the same...

Comment: you're getting a nice comparative set of answers here ...

Comment: This dice game is so much fun. How could you resist. I expect way more answers coming.

Comment: Please do some basic checking of your code before posting. `c(2||3||7||11||12)` returns `TRUE`

Comment: My previous comment was so wrong. How could you roll a 1 with 2 dice... Unbelievable.

Comment: Not to mention probability of rolling a 2 is clearly much less than rolling a 7. Six times less.

Answer (score 3):

I think there are a few issues with your logic.  I'm not quite sure what you're trying to do in your code, but this is my interpretation of your *description* of your problem ...  this only runs a single round of your game -- it should work if you embed it in a `for` loop though (just don't reset `count` or reset the random-number seed in side your loop -- then `count` will give you the total number of rolls, and you can divide by the number of rounds to get the average)

Setup:

```
count = 0
sscore <- c(2,3,7,11,12)
set.seed(101)
debug = TRUE
```

Running a single round:

```
x = sample(1:6,1) +sample(1:6,1)  ## initial roll
count = count + 1
if (x %in% sscore) {
    ## don't need to do anything if we hit,
    ## as the roll has already been counted
    if (debug) cat("hit",x[i],"\n")  
} else {
    ## initialize while loop -- try one more time
    y = c(sample(1:6,1)+sample(1:6,1))
    count = count + 1
    if (debug) cat("initial",x,"next",y,"\n")
    while(!(y %in% c(x,7))) {
        y = c(sample(1:6,1)+sample(1:6,1))
        count = count+1
        if (debug) cat("keep trying",y,"\n")

    }  ## end while
}  ## end if-not-hit
print(count)
```

I tried embedding this in a `for` loop and got a mean of 3.453 for 1000 rounds, close to @PawelP's answer.

PS I hope this isn't homework, as I prefer not to answer homework questions ...

Comment: While the code is fine, for OPs sake I'll point out that the formula for exact value is far from correct. The probability of rolling a number varies between numbers. Also, the stage of "roll initial value or 7" is non trivial to calculate (remember about non uniform probability and that the 7 could've been the initial roll). I lack time to provide the correct formula right now, but surely it's quite more complex (a lot of multiplication, addition, division...)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: I had a bug - forgot to remove `if` negation. Now the below seems to be 100% true to your description of the problem.

This is my implementation of the game you've described. It calculates the average number of rolls it took to end the game over a `TOTAL_GAMES` many games.

```
TOTAL_GAMES = 1000
counts = rep(0, TOTAL_GAMES)
x = NULL
for (i in 1:TOTAL_GAMES) {
    x_start = c(sample(1:6,1) +sample(1:6,1))
    counts[i] = counts[i] + 1
    x = x_start
    if(x %in% c(2, 3, 7, 11, 12)){
       next
    }

    repeat {
        x = c(sample(1:6,1)+sample(1:6,1))
            counts[i] = counts[i] + 1
        if(x %in% c(x_start, 7)){
            break
        }
    }
}

print(mean(counts))
```

It seems that the **average number of rolls is around 3.38**

Comment: nice solution, although I think the use of `next` and `repeat`/`break` are a little bit more confusing in terms of flow (if compact) than my solution ...

Answer (score 1):

Here's one approach to this question - I made a function that runs a single trial, and another function which conducts a variable number of these trials and returns the cumulative average.

```
## Single trial
rollDice <- function(){
  init <- sample(1:6,1)+sample(1:6,1)
  rolls <- 1
  if( init %in% c(2,3,7,11,12) ){
    return(1)
  } else {
    Flag <- TRUE
    while( Flag ){
      roll <- sample(1:6,1)+sample(1:6,1)
      rolls <- rolls + 1
      if( roll %in% c(init,7) ){
        Flag <- FALSE
      }
      rolls
    }
  }
  return(rolls)
}
## Multiple trials
simAvg <- function(nsim = 100){
  x <- replicate(nsim,rollDice())
  Reduce("+",x)/nsim
}
##
## Testing 
nTrial <- seq(1,1000,25)
Results <- sapply(nTrial, function(X){ simAvg(X) })
##
## Plot over varying number of simulations
plot(x=nTrial,y=Results,pch=20)
```

As @Ben Bolker pointed out, you had a couple of syntax errors with `||`, which is understandable for someone new to R. Also, you'll probably hear it a thousand times, but `for` and `while` loops are pretty inefficient in R so you generally want to avoid them if possible. In the case of the `while` loop in the above `rollDice()` function, it probably isn't a big deal because the probability of the loop executing a large number of times is very low. I used the functions `Reduce` and `replicate` to serve the role of a `for` loop in the second function. Good question though, it was fun to work on.

[image]

Comment: I think you've misinterpreted the game description slightly. OP says to re-roll "until the initial total appears or 7", and their (slightly confused) code seems to agree with this interpretation (`if(x[i+1] == c(x[i]||7)) `, which should be `if ([next roll] %in% c([initial roll],7))`

Comment: Oh you're right - thank you for pointing that out, I'll edit the function.